# Not able to Open Project in NetBeans when imported from SVN

Tags: netbeans

```
at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.project.GeneratedFilesHelper$2.run(GeneratedFilesHelper.java:523)
at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:266)
at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.api.jaxws.project.GeneratedFilesHelper.getBuildScriptState(GeneratedFilesHelper.java:482)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.project.WebProject$ProjectOpenedHookImpl.projectOpened(WebProject.java:716)
at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.ProjectOpenedHook$1.projectOpened(ProjectOpenedHook.java:56)
at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.notifyOpened(OpenProjectList.java:593)
at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.doOpenProject(OpenProjectList.java:634)
at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.doOpen(OpenProjectList.java:301)
at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.access$000(OpenProjectList.java:81)
at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList$1.run(OpenProjectList.java:204)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:499)
```

[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:932)

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Yes..I am getting this error.

Comment: I have check all the settings of Environment variable. Not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Yes,this is an question.I have checked all configuration and not sure what to do now.Please help

Comment: Error:- URI has an authority Component

Comment: Guess you should rather file a bug on netbeans bugtracker